# Call back after a click on web object

Tags: c#, 3d, webgl, awesomium

I am working on a Winforms application. We have to display and manipulate a 3D Object that is created and maintained in a Cityengine server somewhere, and the images are served via the internet (kind of like a Google Map 3D). We are using Awesomium to display the 3D images since it is the only one that seems to handle WebGL well.

I want my client to be able to click on some of the 3D objects and after that I want my desktop application to also respond to the click. In other words, I need the Awesomium to have a call back so when the event executes in 3D image immediately notifies the application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JavaScript binding that allows you to call C# code from JavaScript.

Something like:

```
JSObject interfaceBinding = webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("bindingObject");
interfaceBinding.Bind("myFunction", false, myHandler);
```

With your hander function looking simular to something like this:

```
private void myHandler(object sender, JavascriptMethodEventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever you want with e.Arguments containg the arguments from the js call
}
```

This will create an object called 'bindingObject' as global JavaScript object and you can call it with

```
window.bindingObject.myFunction(yourParmeters,...);
```

EDIT: The click event is of course handled in JavaScript in the web view and I just assume you know how to do it, if not (and there is no high-level api): search the web for 'webGL picking' to learn about the different possible approaches (for example color-picking, ray-picking, etc) that can be used in webGL.